# Can JAXB generate ArrayList instead of List?

Tags: java, collections, jaxb, arraylist

```
<complexType name="BookShelf">
   <sequence>
      <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
         <element name="newBook" type="string"/>
         <element name="oldBook" type="string"/>
      </choice>
   </sequence>
</complexType>
```

JAXB generates the property as a `List<JAXBElement<String>>`. Is there any way it can be generated as ArrayList?

Comment: Why? JAXB generated a kind of API from the schema. An API should not contain concrete classes. ArrayList has only one public method more than List: trimToSize(), is this essential for you? By the way: the generated code creates an ArrrayList instances in lazy getters.

Answer (score 14):

## Why, what good would that do you?

1. [`ArrayList<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) has no public
   methods that are not in the
   [`List<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface, so there is
   nothing you could do with the
   `ArrayList<E>` that you couldn't do
   with any other `List<E>` (actually
   there is one:
   [`ArrayList.trimToSize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize%28%29),
   thanks @Joachim Sauer, but it's
   hardly ever needed).
2. It's awful practice for an API to
   accept or return implementation
   types instead of the underlying
   interfaces. I'd suggest you to
   follow the [Collections Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) of
   the Sun Java Tutorial and / or read
   [Effective Java by Joshua Bloch](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)
   (you'll get an idea of what he's
   talking about [from this short
   preview](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/general-programming/ch08lev1sec8), which is the source of the quote below) to learn more about the
   Collections framework and interface
   usage.
3. Who says the underlying List
   implementation isn't `ArrayList`?
   `ArrayList` is the most
   commonly-used List implementation
   anyway, so chances are high that
   JAXB will actually return an
   `ArrayList`, it just won't tell you
   so (because you don't need to know).

## Item 52: Refer to Objects by their Interfaces (excerpt)

> Item 40 contains the advice that you
>   should use interfaces rather than
>   classes as parameter types. More
>   generally, you should favor the use of
>   interfaces rather than classes to
>   refer to objects. **If appropriate
>   interface types exist, then
>   parameters, return values, variables,
>   and fields should all be declared
>   using interface types.** The only time
>   you really need to refer to an
>   object’s class is when you’re creating
>   it with a constructor. To make this
>   concrete, consider the case of
>   `Vector`, which is an implementation
>   of the `List` interface. Get in the
>   habit of typing this:

```
// Good - uses interface as type
List<Subscriber> subscribers = new Vector<Subscriber>();
```

> rather than this:

```
// Bad - uses class as type!
Vector<Subscriber> subscribers = new Vector<Subscriber>();
```

[ ... ]

**Source:** Effective Java, [preview on SafariBooksOnline](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/general-programming/ch08lev1sec8).

Comment: Item #1 is not entirely correct (see `trimToSize()`, mentioned by Arne above).

Comment: @Joachim darn, yes, I missed that one :-)

Comment: It's rude to answer a question with another one.

Comment: @jonbros perhaps, but it would have been unforgivable to answer the question literally without making the OP aware of the flaws in his Question

Comment: @jonbros No, I didn't *forget* to answer the question, I *chose* not to answer it literally. Others did answer it literally but I chose to challenge the question instead. And apparently I'm not alone with my views. Go ahead, answer some questions, get some rep and downvote my answer, but it will still be the only appropriate way to answer this question.

Answer (score 5):

By default the property will be a List and the underlying implementation will be an ArrayList.  Of course you can use JAXB customizations to change the underlying implementation, or use your own class with a property of type ArrayList (although for the reasons mentioned in other answers this is rarely a good idea).

**Default JAXB Generation**

Given your XML Schema:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <complexType name="BookShelf">
      <sequence>
         <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <element name="newBook" type="string"/>
            <element name="oldBook" type="string"/>
         </choice>
      </sequence>
   </complexType>
</schema>
```

Using the following command line:

```
xjc -d out your-schema.xsd
```

JAXB will generate the following class:

```
package generated;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRefs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BookShelf", propOrder = {
    "newBookOrOldBook"
})
public class BookShelf {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "newBook", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "oldBook", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    protected List<JAXBElement<String>> newBookOrOldBook;

    public List<JAXBElement<String>> getNewBookOrOldBook() {
        if (newBookOrOldBook == null) {
            newBookOrOldBook = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<String>>();
        }
        return this.newBookOrOldBook;
    }

}
```

**Customizing the Generation**

By default JAXB will have the property type be List with the underlying implementation being ArrayList.  If you wish to control the underlying implementation you can use an external binding file like:

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="f3.xsd">
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='BookShelf']/xs:sequence/xs:choice">
                <jxb:property collectionType="java.util.LinkedList"/>
            </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

And the following XJC call:

```
xjc -d out -b binding.xml your-schema.xsd
```

To get the following class instead:

```
package generated;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRefs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BookShelf", propOrder = {
    "newBookOrOldBook"
})
public class BookShelf {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "oldBook", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "newBook", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    protected List<JAXBElement<String>> newBookOrOldBook = new LinkedList<JAXBElement<String>>();

    public List<JAXBElement<String>> getNewBookOrOldBook() {
        if (newBookOrOldBook == null) {
            newBookOrOldBook = new LinkedList<JAXBElement<String>>();
        }
        return this.newBookOrOldBook;
    }

}
```

**Using your own class:**

You can also use your own class with a property of type ArrayList (although for the reasons mentioned in other answers this is rarely a good idea).

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRefs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BookShelf", propOrder = {
    "newBookOrOldBook"
})
public class BookShelf {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "oldBook", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "newBook", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    protected ArrayList<JAXBElement<String>> newBookOrOldBook ;

    public ArrayList<JAXBElement<String>> getNewBookOrOldBook() {
        if (newBookOrOldBook == null) {
            newBookOrOldBook = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<String>>();
        }
        return this.newBookOrOldBook;
    }

}
```

**For More Information:**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/01/jaxb-and-choosing-list-implementation.htm

Comment: Like your post. Thanks. But what if you would want to use Sets instead of Lists or any other collection type?

Comment: @jonbros - If you start with Java classes you can use a property of type set or other collection type.  If you start from XML schema I do not believe you can cause it to generate a set.  Although you may be able to make this happen with an XJC plug-in:  http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html

Comment: Yes, starting from XML. I'll have a look at the plugin. I read about User-Defined-Datatypes here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webserv/data_types.html#wp221622

It says for java.utils.Set the "Equivalent XML Schema Data Type" is Literal Array. But I dont know what thats suppose to mean. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the fact that the API generates a List.

However, assuming that the underlying implementation actually produces an ArrayList you can always just cast it to an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<JAXBElement<String>> arrayList = 
        (ArrayList<JAXBElement<String>>) list;
```

Or if it isn't an arraylist (i.e. you get an exception trying the above...), you can generate a new ArrayList containing the same elements of the list.

```
ArrayList<JAXBElement<String>> arrayList = 
        new ArrayList<JAXBElement<String>>(list);
```

In general however, you shouldn't need to do any of this: it's always better to code against an interface abstraction rather than the underlying concrete class whenever you can.

Comment: this is a classic +1 / -1 post. On the technical side, it's good to share this, but you should a) put more emphasis on this being an awful practice (perhaps replace *shouldn't need* with *shouldn't*) and b) a cast should hardly ever take place without an `instanceof` check.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd - for me it's a definite (+1) because (1) it gives a solution to the problem and (2) I don't know the actual requirements to do it. Maybe there *is* a good reason. Maybe not, but then he should study *your* answer ;)

Comment: Hi Sean: IMO casts without instanceof checks are perfectly good practice in many circumstances. it just means that you either know or are willing to make an assumption about the underlying concrete class. if that assumption turns out to be wrong you get a runtime exception, which is exactly the correct behaviour..... it's analogous to the way that you don't need to put a try / catch around every function call that might possibly cause an exception.