# What customization to apply for JAX-WS to unwrap return objects to lists?

Tags: java, jax-ws, wsimport, jax-ws-customization

I am trying to find if there is a way to customize e.g. `CSID2ExtRefs` operation for [ChemSpider WebService](http://www.chemspider.com/Search.asmx?WSDL) that is passed a list of strings as one of the arguments and returns the list of objects:

```
<!-- Request element: -->
<s:element name="CSID2ExtRefs">
  <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CSID" type="s:int"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="datasources" type="tns:ArrayOfString"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="token" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
</s:element>
<!-- Response element: -->
<s:element name="CSID2ExtRefsResponse">
  <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CSID2ExtRefsResult" type="tns:ArrayOfExtRef"/>
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfExtRef">
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ExtRef" type="tns:ExtRef"/>
  </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfString">
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="string" nillable="true" type="s:string"/>
  </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

The generated by `wsimport` interface method is (with `jaxws:enableWrapperStyle = true`):

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "CSID2ExtRefs", action = "http://www.chemspider.com/CSID2ExtRefs")
@WebResult(name = "CSID2ExtRefsResult", targetNamespace = "http://www.chemspider.com/")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "CSID2ExtRefs", targetNamespace = "http://www.chemspider.com/", className = "chemspider.core.CSID2ExtRefsRequest")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "CSID2ExtRefsResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.chemspider.com/", className = "chemspider.core.CSID2ExtRefsResponse")
public ArrayOfExtRef csid2ExtRefs(
    @WebParam(name = "CSID", targetNamespace = "http://www.chemspider.com/")
    int csid,
    @WebParam(name = "datasources", targetNamespace = "http://www.chemspider.com/")
    ArrayOfString datasources,
    @WebParam(name = "token", targetNamespace = "http://www.chemspider.com/")
    String token);
```

but I would like to have `ArrayOfExtRef` and `ArrayOfString` unwrapped and turned to lists e.g. get the following:

```
public List<ExtRef> csid2ExtRefs(
    @WebParam(...)
    int csid,
    @WebParam(...)
    List<String> datasources,
    @WebParam(...)
    String token);
```

If I make this change manually, JAX-WS works fine. I wonder, if there any way to write an appropriate [customization](http://jax-ws.java.net/jax-ws-20-fcs/docs/customizations.html) for that?

Comment: Finally filed a [ticket](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-1037).

Comment: Haven't tried this particular case, but, you can control the binding behavior of jaxb for the sequences.  You may still have a problem with the complex type that is specified, though.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4795219/659138 and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webserv/data_types.html#wp218717 for more information on controlling the binding behavior.

Comment: The post you refer is about customizing the class used as collection implementation for `<sequence>`. What I need is unwrapping: I have played with `enableWrapperStyle` but that does not help much. I need something like [`jaxb-xew-plugin`](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin) but for JAX-WS.

Comment: @dma_k what philwb says might not be exactly what you are looking for but he does point you in the right direction. JAX-WS has nothing to do with this. JAX-B is what the actual Java classes generates based on the XSD. If you want change the Java classes you need to make configuration changes to JAX-B, not JAX-WS.

Comment: @JasperSiepkes: I understand what hint is about. It's clear that `ArrayOfExtRef` is generated by JAXB, but SEI with method `csid2ExtRefs()` was generated by JAX-WS and it takes a decision concerning the return type of this method. JAXB by principle cannot "generate" `List<ExtRef>` return type as it should be some model class. Although I might be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

First off all web service std are not 100% portable yet.
Replace

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="datasources" type="tns:ArrayOfString"/>
```

with

```
<s:element name="datasources" type="xs:string" form="qualified" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
```

also replace

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CSID2ExtRefsResult" type="tns:ArrayOfExtRef"/>
```

with

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="CSID2ExtRefsResult" type="tns:ExtRef"/>
```

Also you may remove complexType such as "ArrayOfString",ArrayOfExtRef.

Comment: This approach is clear, +1 for efforts. One can write XSD transformation to achieve this. However the question was about JAX-WS customization ability.

Comment: hmm thanks for +1, for customization you may have to look for adaptors

Comment: AFAIK, adapters are only applicable for class properties. Well, adapters are from JAXB world, and what we are trying to trick is SEI which is generated and processed by JAX-WS. We can't apply adapter to `List<ExtRef>` (JDK class), and (I am pretty sure) can't use `@XmlAdapter` on SEI method for example or SEI method arguments. Let me know if you find something breaking-through in this area.